# What condition is required to break numbers in ms excel to calculate cost

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am sorry, if the question title is not self-explanatory. Here are the details.

How can I set conditions/formula in MS Excel, if I input number '250' units

**Costing Rule-1:** If units are from **0 to 100** then price is 5.00
**Costing Rule-2:** If units are from **101 to 200** then price is 8.00
**Costing Rule-3:** If units are from **201 to 300** then price is 10.50

Therefore formula should calculate like this: (100*5)+(100*8)+(50*10.50) = 1825

Comment: Create new column that calculates the price for the items and include an `IF` in the formula. In natural language it would be `If the amount of units is greater than 0 and less than 101 the price is 5 times the amount. If the amount of units is greater than 100 and less than 201 the price is 8 times the mount ...`

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! Can you please create a formula which can do calculation like this (100*5)+(100*8)+(50*10.50) = 1825? I understand your meaning but still I am failing to do so.

Comment: No. Look at the [help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) on how `IF` work and it should become clear. What did you try? Where do you get stuck? You will need to nest an if for every rule. In addition with your initial question you will have to split the initial number for each part. You could do this in various ways.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "amount" is in cell A1, then your formula is

```
=IF(A1<=100;A1*5;100*5+IF(A1<=200;(A1-100)*8;100*8+IF(A1<=300;(A1-200)*10,5;100*10,5)))
```

But as you see, there are some constant values so you can simplify it to

```
=IF(A1<=100;A1*5;500+IF(A1<=200;(A1-100)*8;800+IF(A1<=300;(A1-200)*10,5;1050)))
```

Perhaps you have to replace `;` through `,` in your version of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

After giving it a bit of thought I came up with the same solution as IQV but spaced it out a bit more. Maybe it's easier to understand that way. I was curious about the splitting.

[image: A graphical representation of the calculation]

It's a more verbose approach to the same calculation.

The formula for `B3`, `B4`, and `B5` would be:

```
=IF($B$1<=100; $B$1; 100)
=IF($B$1<=200; IF($B1-100 > 0; $B$1-100; 0); 100)
=IF($B$1<=300; IF($B$1-200 > 0; $B$1-200; 0); 100)
```

The formula for the sum would be an easy multiplication (`=B3*C3+B4*C4+B5*C5`).

By nesting those `IF` statements you can save the trouble of checking whenever one of the amounts would be zero. An obvious drawback would be there is no definition for what happens if you exceed an amount of 300 units. As such, with both approaches, you would end up giving away those units for free. The advantage of this more verbose approach is that it becomes easily apparent as the sum of units won't exceed 300 units.

To change this behavior you would just need to change the `B5` formula to not have a condition. In my example you would need to change it to `IF($B$1-200 > 0; $B$1-200; 0)`